# Flutter audioplayers: How to handle PlatformException(AndroidAudioError, Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread)

Tags: android, flutter, multithreading, dart, flutter-audioplayers

I am using audioplayers (4.0.1) to play some short audio. The function runs ok as I can hear the audio gets played, but I see those warning messages in my console.

I am super new to Flutter, so my question is, should I care about this message, if so, how should I handle this unhandled exception?

I don't know in dart how to clearly ask to run a function on the ui thread.

```
  AudioPlayer? _player;
  void _play(number) async {
    _player?.dispose();
    final player = _player = AudioPlayer();
    print("trying to play number $number");
    player.play(AssetSource('audio/$number.wav'));
  }

...

 itemBuilder: (context, index){
   _play(index+1);
   return Colum(...)
}
```

```
I/flutter (32755): trying to play number 3
V/MediaPlayer(32755): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer(32755): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
V/MediaPlayer(32755): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer(32755): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
E/flutter (32755): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(AndroidAudioError, Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1, java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
E/flutter (32755):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.ensureRunningOnMainThread(FlutterJNI.java:1415)
E/flutter (32755):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.dispatchEmptyPlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:1015)
E/flutter (32755):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.send(DartMessenger.java:280)
E/flutter (32755):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor$DefaultBinaryMessenger.send(DartExecutor.java:452)
E/flutter (32755):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor.send(DartExecutor.java:212)
E/flutter (32755):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel$IncomingStreamRequestHandler$EventSinkImplementation.endOfStream(EventChannel.java:270)
E/flutter (32755):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.EventHandler.endOfStream(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:354)
E/flutter (32755):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.WrappedPlayer.dispose(WrappedPlayer.kt:356)
E/flutter (32755):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin.handler(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:197)
E/flutter (32755):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin.access$handler(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:29)
E/flutter (32755):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$onAttachedToEngine$1$1.invoke(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:50)
E/flutter (32755):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$onAttachedToEngine$1$1.invoke(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:50)
E/flutter (32755):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$safeCall$1.invokeSuspend(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:74)
E/flutter (32755):  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
E/flutter (32755):  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
E/flutter (32755):  at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
E/flutter (32755):  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
E/flutter (32755):  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
E/flutter (32755):  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
E/flutter (32755):  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
E/flutter (32755):  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
E/flutter (32755): , null)
E/flutter (32755): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
E/flutter (32755): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:315:18)
E/flutter (32755): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (32755): #2      AudioPlayer.dispose (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:353:5)
E/flutter (32755): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems it was a bug and they fixed it two days ago: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues/1481

Don't know when will they release that fix.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing a PlatformException error, only with some Android devices, but not all.
My solution was to change to the `just_audio` package:

https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio

It also supports url, assets, files and streams sources and it fixed my problem.

Comment: i changed pubspec.yaml to run most recent version in GIT, and it resolved my issues, but i still switched to just_audio because it was far more simple in the way i was using it, released stable version worked, and it played the same m4a audio louder than audioplayers. for folks that want to stick with audioplayers, the code to run audioplayers from GIT:   audioplayers:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers.git
      path: packages/audioplayers